# Create an object from Model B while editing an object from Model A?

Tags: django

Hi I'm pretty new to Django and I'm trying to create an app with a Project model, and a Task model. Every project has one or more tasks. The thing I want to do is add a TaskHistory model, and every task has one or more taskhistory. Everytime I change something in my task (because this will be something that I'll have to edit a lot) I want a new associated TaskHistory to be created. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible, but something that is likely to be coded at the application/view layer rather than directly in the Django models.  What you're attempting appears to closely match the log entries that are created as part of the standard `django.contrib.admin` application so you should look in this app for ideas.  `django.contrib.admin` will log an entry to a `LogEntry` table every time an object is updated, created or deleted in the admin interface.

It's likely for your application that you'll need to store changes in model content such as a change in a task description, not simply whether a task was created.  To achieve this, you're likely to require both the current task object and the updated task details to be able to create a `TaskHistory` object.

Each view that is capable of modifying a task would also include logic which could create a `TaskHistory` object, and save both the updated/new `Task` and the `TaskHistory` objects as independent model objects, possibly wrapped in a database level transaction to make the changes appear atomically.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however I found how to do what I meant by using the signals (for instance, the post_save signal).